# how to do an sql join on the closest approximation

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, hana

I have a data table where the relevant column contains a number. I want to join this to a reference table which contains an order list of numbers and I want to match each row in the data table to the closest number (close as in smallest difference) in the reference table.

I could do something like

```
Select top 1 ref_number 
from reference 
where ref_number < data_number
order by ref_number desc
```

do something similar with `ref_number > data_number` find the smallest difference and then join. This would work but would be a big mess of code for a seemingly simple operation and as it requires going through the entire reference table twice for every single row of the data table I would assume it would be very slow as well (the reference table has around 25000 entries, the data table has around 1 million).

So question: is there a more efficient way to match the closest number from a reference table to each entry in a data table? If both tables are ordered by their numbers it should be much easier to make the matches but I can't quite see the SQL code to do it.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to get.

Reference table

```
ref_number  other reference columns 
1           ..
3
6
10
```

Data table

```
data_number 
1           
7
9.2
```

Target table

```
data_number ref_number other reference columns
1           1          ..
7           6
9.2         10
```

Comment: You can use a table expression or you can use a lateral query. It depends on the specific database. Which database are you using?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RANK window function](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/Cloud/en-US/10bb583b586e47a09790eb8f8eeeab62.html) to achieve this kind of join. Please find a snippet with the relevant pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_ref (id integer, value double);
INSERT INTO tab_ref VALUES (1, 1.0);
INSERT INTO tab_ref VALUES (2, 3.0);
INSERT INTO tab_ref VALUES (3, 6.0);
INSERT INTO tab_ref VALUES (4, 10.0);

CREATE TABLE tab_data (id integer, value double);
INSERT INTO tab_data VALUES (1, 1.0);
INSERT INTO tab_data VALUES (2, 7.0);
INSERT INTO tab_data VALUES (3, 9.2);
    
    
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY ABS(a.value - b.value)) AS rnk
    FROM tab_ref a, tab_data b
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may generate two intervals for each reference value: one interval is below the current value and another interval is above. Then two joins by `between` predicate will assign two reference values to each `data_number`: one value is higher than current `data_number` and another one is lower. And then decide which one is closer.

The code is below (based on Postgres fiddle, but the syntax is the same for most of the modern DBMS).

> ```
> insert into base_tab (data_number)
> values (0), (1), (4.5), (7), (9.2)
> ```

> ```
> insert into ref_tab (ref_number)
> values (1), (3), (6), (9)
> ```

> ```
> with fromto as (
>   select
>     ref_number as num
>     /*
>       Identify the first and the last row
>       in the data set to manage values below
>       the lowest (in the reference data set)
>       and above the highest
>     */
>     , lag(0, 1, 1)
>       over(order by ref_number asc)
>       as first_row
>     , lead(0, 1, 1)
>       over(order by ref_number asc)
>       as last_row
>     /*
>       And add value ranges (before and after current ref_num)
>       to match data_number as closest above
>       or closest below
>     */
>     , lead(ref_number, 1, 999999999999999.0)
>       over(order by ref_number asc)
>       as next_num
>     , lag(ref_number, 1, -999999999999999.0)
>       over(order by ref_number asc)
>       as prev_num
>   from ref_tab
> )
>
> select
>   b.*
>   , case
>       /*
>         When the data_number is below the lowest
>         in the reference data set, then use the lowest
>         value from reference data set
>       */
>       when up_.first_row = 1
>       then up_.num
>       /*
>         When the data_number is above the highest
>         in the reference data set, then use the highest
>         value from reference data set
>       */
>       when down_.last_row = 1
>       then down_.num
>       /*
>         Assign the closest value from the reference
>         data set with minimal difference.
>         Lower value has higher priority
>       */
>       when b.data_number - down_.num
>         <= up_.num - b.data_number
>       then down_.num
>       when up_.num - b.data_number
>         > b.data_number - down_.num
>       then up_.num
>     end as ref_num
> from base_tab as b
>   /*Test if data_number is below current ref_num*/
>   left join fromto as up_
>     on
>       b.data_number >= up_.prev_num
>       and b.data_number < up_.num
>   /*Test if data_number is above current ref_num*/
>   left join fromto as down_
>     on
>       b.data_number >= down_.num
>       and b.data_number < down_.next_num
> ```

> ```
> data_number | ref_num
> ----------: | ------:
>           0 |       1
>           1 |       1
>         4.5 |       3
>           7 |       6
>         9.2 |       9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9d3c6fc7461889adaa5701e0843f9c0b)*

**UPD**: Please note, that range joins will require loops anyway because there's no any equality and DBMS needs to test every row (entire table or from some starting point in sorted data set). You may try to implement some improvements with explicit loops over sorted data (sort merge join) in procedural extension (SQL Script in case of HANA), but I think that this is the work for optimizer and should be done behind the scenes implicitly.