# Rolling joins with database backends

Tags: r, join, dplyr, dbplyr

Version 1.1.0 of `dplyr` acquired features that allow it to express complex joins; for example one can now express [rolling joins](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/#rolling-joins). I believe that at the moment (as of `dbplyr` 2.3.0) there is no translation of these constructs into SQL. I was curious about:

1. I assume that the plan is to provide backend translations for most of these new constructs. Is this correct?
2. If so, I was wondering what the likely translation of these constructs would be for the MS SQL Server backend?  For example, what are possible T-SQL translations for the likes of `join_by(company == id, closest(year >= since))`?

Comment: (1) It's a good question, I suggest you [ask the authors/maintainers](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/new/choose). (2) An example: `... from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.company = t2.id and t1.year >= t2.since` would likely first go in a CTE, which is then sub-queried for a [closest approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743104/3358272). (Yes, a bit of hand-waving here, but I think the real answer to that is more appropriate in the `dbplyr` [repo](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr), not here.) (3) I'm also looking forward to `join_by` in arrow, thanks for asking :-)

Comment: In the meantime, this answer should assist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74892950/7742981

Comment: @Simon.S.A. I don't think `sql_on` will suffice for these kinds of rolling joins (where one might use `closest`). For example, in the answer that @r2evans links to the query uses `PARTITION BY` and then `RANK()`. The other approach that might work is an `OUTER APPLY`. However, if you can implement this kind of join using `sql_on` please tell me!

Comment: Fair point. Sorry, I did not fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that rolling joins *not* being supported by `dbplyr` was confirmed in a [discussion of a join_by() pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/pull/1074#discussion_r1103644260) (two days after my question). The same thread suggests that perhaps some backends will eventually support it. It does not indicate when support will appear, nor how it will be implemented.